# How to get the media player to play audio files from the app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having difficulties to play the audio files from within my app here is my code:

```
Integer[] mAudio = {
    R.raw.audioa,
    R.raw.audiob,
    R.raw.audioc,
    R.raw.audiod,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playing);  
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery4);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id){

final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image7);
imageView.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
mageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
Public void onClick(View arg0) {

    android.media.MediaPlayer.create(Audio.this,mAudio[position]);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);                           

         }
});
```

The idea is when the user selects the image  from the gallery and then selects the larger image the audio should play.  However when I use this code:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Owls.this,mAudio[position]);  
 mp.start();
```

it then works great, but can't stop the audio and when exiting the app (home key or back key) the audio keeps playing.  What I need to achieve is to when the users selects the image it should then ask which player you would want to use and then play the audio track for that image.  At the moment it just brings up my entire media library and not the audio file specified in this code:

```
android.media.MediaPlayer.create(Birds.this,mAudio[position]);
```

And it should only play the audio file for that image and not bring up the entire audio tracks for this app.
Any one have got any idea and please be able to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will solve your one of the issue:('can't stop the audio and when exiting the app (home key or back key) the audio keeps playing')

This part has to be in EVERY activity's onPause:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
          ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
          if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            player.stop();
            Toast.makeText(xYourClassNamex.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
```

So you can stop your player when you are exit from app.

Comment: Thank you, but what I want to achieve is to play the audio file through the media player so that the user can stop and replay if they want to.